# How should shopping recommendations be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging

See title, essentially. Currently there isn't an explicit option on the flag menu to flag as "Off-topic -> Shopping recommendation", despite it being listed as an off-topic category in the [Help Centre](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

What would be the correct way of flagging such posts? Is it simply a case of "this is not about Ubuntu", or should there be a different option? (For reference, the question in... well, question is this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/416805/ubuntu-laptop-questions)

Comment: I normally close as primarily opinion based due the great influx of opinions.

Comment: Too broad works too.

Comment: I went with opinion-based, but feel like a specific off-topic category could be helpful since opinions aren't really the primary reason here. It's listed specifically in the help, so I don't particularly see why it isn't in the flag list. Just my opinion, though (perhaps slightly ironically)